# export html table in excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have tried to export html tables into excel tbl1 and tbl5 in ProductDay1 sheet and tbl2 in ProductDay2 sheet .In my example I can able to get only  tabl1 in ProductDay1 but I need both tbl1 and tbl5 in ProductDay1 sheet and tbl2 in ProductDay2.My Fiddle to download excel [**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ofLn8z02/1/)

```js
  var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
      + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
      + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
      + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
          rowsXML += '<Row>'
          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
          rowsXML += '</Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
      }

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

console.log(workbookXML);

      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
```

```html
  
  <button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
  <table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bred</td>
                        <td>1
</td>
                        <td>2
</td>
                        <td>3
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>4
</td>
                        <td>5
</td>
                        <td >6
</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<hr>
   <table id="tbl5" class="table2excel">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bred</td>
                        <td>1
</td>
                        <td>2
</td>
                        <td>3
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>4
</td>
                        <td>5
</td>
                        <td >6
</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <hr>
  <table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Available</td>
                        <td>Count</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bred</td>
                        <td>7
</td>
                        <td>8
</td>
                        <td>9
</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Butter</td>
                        <td>14
</td>
                        <td>15
</td>
                        <td >16
</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: what if you can make the each table as csv (text) , and then put the csv in what ever place you want in your xls file ?

Comment: can you please give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issues is you are creating the sheet before looping into the other once :

exactly here :

```
ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
rowsXML = "";
```

this code working fine , but your `rowsXML` , is alredy saved and you did move to the other sheet.

what you can do is change the loop approch , or maybe store the rows and nameWS in a dictionary , wait unti the and of the loop and you can call those above lines.

to better understand what i mean , you can  change your code to this  :

```
  ctx = {rows: rowsXML + rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
```

and then you will see that the same table is duplicated in each sheet. so the whole work that you need to do is to fill rowsXML with all tables in the same sheet before looping to other table or sheet.

**EDIT:**

first let's say that this presentation here :

```
 <button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

is not helpful in your case.
perhabs if it was like that :

```
 <button  onclick="tablesToExcel( [{ 'sheet': 'firstsheet','tables' : ['tbl1','tbl2']},{ 'sheet': 'secondsheet','tables' : ['tbl5']}], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

because in this cases you are setting your sheet first.

**EDIT:**
and here is your working code fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/ad2mejco/

html :

```
 <button  onclick="tablesToExcel( [{ 'sheet': 'firstsheet','tables' : ['tbl1','tbl2']},{ 'sheet': 'secondsheet','tables' : ['tbl5']}], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

Js:

```
  var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
      + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
      + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
      + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(data, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";
     
     for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
     console.log(data[x]["sheet"]);
     
    tables = data[x]["tables"];
     
        for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
                  rowsXML += '<Row>'

          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
               rowsXML += '</Row>'

        }
   
      }
     
     

         ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: data[x]["sheet"] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";

     }
     

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

console.log(workbookXML);

      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
```

Comment: can you please give the fiddle example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ofLn8z02/2/ second table is replicating there.Please help

Comment: i will see what i can do for your fiddle once  i got some time :) ...

Comment: I got the error for arrow http://jsfiddle.net/ofLn8z02/4/

Comment: double check the code above  , if you need a speration between both table you can add a empty row :) ...

Comment: is it possible to display the table horizontally instead of vertical with space

Comment: yes you can , move the row closing and opening to the loop before and add column :) , try to play with those attributes , it's simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217905/discussion-between-user3386779-and-moxgeek).